# How to hide Foldcolumn in Vim?

Tags: vim, folding

I tried to hide a foldcolumn in VIM via .vimrc :

```
set foldcolumn=0
```

but it doesn't work. It always appears as an extra column.

Commenting "set foldcolumn=0" didn't work too.

Comment: Before adding an option to your `~/.vimrc`, always try it in the command line: `:set foldcolumn=0`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a buffer-local option, `'foldcolumn'` is probably set by a *filetype plugin*, especially because its global default value is 0.

When the fold column appears, find out where it got set via `:verbose setlocal foldcolumn?`. Then, e.g. when it was set by `ftplugin/cpp.vim`, you can put the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
:setlocal foldcolumn=0
```

The *after directory* allows to override filetype-specific settings without modifying the original script.

Answer (score 0):

For me some automatic folding options were done by the [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) plugin. [Ingo's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18666580/4515565) tip worked good when I created the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/pandoc.vim` with his recommendations; however, the plugin reloaded at times and its folding settings returned. With the vim-pandoc plugin its own settings have to be used. I set the column width to 0 and opted to do folding on my own:

```
: let g:pandoc#folding#mode = ['manual']
: let g:pandoc#folding#fdc = 0
```